# Format several input streams into columns

Tags: shell, text

How can I format lines of text from several input streams, into columns side-by-side?

The [`column` command](http://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/1/column/) seems to promise to do this, but it doesn't behave as expected:

```bash
$ column -t \
    <(for n in {1..4} ; do echo $n ; done) \
    <(for n in {8..11} ; do echo $n ; done)
1
2
3
4
8
9
10
11
```

The promise (from the manual page) to “Determine the number of columns the input contains and create a table” does not appear to be the case.

What I want instead is:

```bash
$ some_clever_command --with-clever-options \
    <(for n in {1..4} ; do echo $n ; done) \
    <(for n in {8..11} ; do echo $n ; done)
1       8
2       9
3       10
4       11
```

What command and options should I use for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `paste` command can do this:

```bash
$ paste -d '\t\n' \
    <(for n in {1..4} ; do echo $n ; done) \
    <(for n in {8..11} ; do echo $n ; done)
1   2
3   4
8   9
10  11
```